# Building Docker images with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins inside of a container; however, my Jenkinsfile fails to build the Docker image and throws this error:

> Running shell script
>   + docker build -t 11207b4dde319c028c35cc11eff8216939cf96f5 -f Dockerfile . docker: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libltdl.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I do not want to follow the solution which is to run docker inside docker by installing the docker client inside my jenkins image.

And bind-mounting the docker.sock file doesn't seem to work

Any ideas?

Here's my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2 AS build-env
RUN dotnet --version
```

Jenkinsfile (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'dotnet --version'
                sh 'docker --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATES***
To fix this issue, I ended up updating my Dockerfile to apt-get install the missing library

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
COPY executors.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy
#Installing missing libs required for jenkins to run on docker 
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get upgrade -y \
      && apt-get install -y sudo libltdl-dev \
      && apt-get install apt-utils -y \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

And I call this Dockerfile with my docker-compose.yml like below:

```
version: '3.1'

#Repo: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/
#Doc: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

services:
  jenkins_server:
    build: .
    image: joel/jenkins:manager #gives a name to our image that we just built
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  #master port on Docker host mapping to 8080 inside the container
      - "50000:50000"  #used for slave agents - not needed to ssh slaves

    volumes:
      - $HOME/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home #let docker manage the volume on the host to avoid file permission issues when the jenkins user doesn't have enough perm to access this location on a different machine
      - $HOME/jenkins_home/logs:/var/log/jenkins/ #https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock #Giving the agent the capacity to run docker containers
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

My only issue now is jenkins is running as "root" to avoid a permission issue I keep running into; even when I add the jenkins user to the docker group it still doesn't work so I just run jenkins as root for now until I find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution for creating docker images using Jenkins to mount the docker socket.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker ...
```

Comment: I'm running docker via docker-compose and I already included those volumes in my compose file but it's still not working. I update my dockerfile to include the missing library, see my updated question above, thank you!